# Restlet webService on the cloud

Tags: java, cloud, restlet

I have built a Java Web Service for my app using `restlet`.
It's pure Java and standalone.
Is there any free cloud service where i can host my webservice?

It has really minimal requirements.
One of them is a static IP.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Use jelastic.com..
Its easy to use and supports java web applications and many databases.

[Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/)

Comment: As far as i can see it has only two weeks free trail. I need something for the long term.

Comment: I dont believe there are many cloud services which provide long term free usage.. You have to pay them ultimately to enjoy cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

Restlet works fine with Google App Engine thanks to its GAE edition. CloudFoundry / AppFog can also be an interesting solution... Perhaps can you have a look at that?

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

From Restlet creator, I think.
http://apispark.com/

Comment: At this moment, APISpark doesn't let you import existing Restlet application in APISpark. However, it does let you export APISpark API as Restlet applications.